# SQL Access db - select every third row from database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

How can I select every thrid row from the table?

if a table has

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

records
it should pick up 3, 6,9 record. regards less what their data is.

Comment: Can we assume no gaps in the table?

Comment: what do you mean by gaps? empty rows. yes there is no empty rows.

Comment: Don't think so - he said "regardless what their data is", so you can't just get the multiples of 3 from the data.

Comment: I can't fathom why people are always wanting to select random sets of data like this. I've been writing Access database applications professionally since 1996 and haven't once needed anything like this. Why do you think you need every third record? How can that possibly be a meaningful result (as opposed to a pseudo-random one)?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - I worked with high-speed film analysis in grad school and it was common to only include every 3rd, 5th, 8th, 25th frame if you're plotting positions manually. Data entry is easier if the app can select only the required records. Since then, I pretty much work with business money transaction data, so I see your point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modulo is what you want...

Assuming contiguous values:

```
SELECT *
FROM Mytable
WHERE [TheColumn] Mod 3 = 0
```

And with gaps

```
SELECT *
FROM Mytable
WHERE DCount("TheColumn", "table", "TheColumn <= " & [TheColumn]) Mod 3 = 0
```

Edit: To exclude every 3rd record, `...Mod 3 <> 0`

Comment: is there any way i can update it. infact there are 14000 records in my table. I want to fetch 10000 randomely. i use Mode 2 =0 it gives me 7k and if i use 3=0 it gives me 4.5k aprox. can I get exact amount 10,000 and radom as well. any idea?

Comment: @Ghost: you can't get random 10k rows from 14k records with modulo. I'd suggest you ask a new question with what you *really* want. You asked for "every 3rd row" and that is what you got.

Comment: how can i exclude every third record

Comment: Thanks I figured that out. You know sometime when you need to do things quickly and a lot of stuff needs to be done in less time. brain does not work at that time ;)

Answer (score 0):

If its SQL you could use the row_number and over commands. see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), then where `rownumvar % 3 =0` but not sure if that works in access.

Or you could put the table into a recordset and iterate through checking the index for `% 3=0` if your using any kind of code.

How about a `Count()` on a field that has unique members. `(id?)` then `% 3` on that.

Comment: By "If its SQL" do you mean "if it's SQL Server"? The original question was tagged ACCESS, so it's pretty clearly not SQL Server. Access/Jet/ACE has no row_number function/command. You might want to read the tags more carefully.